# Windows 7 will not install

Tags: windows-7, installation

Last weekend I was having black screens and I figured I was due for a reinstall anyway.

The install starts normally and at every attempt at 50% I get this error:

> Windows cannot install required files error 0x80070570 The file may be
>   corrupt or missing.. Make sure all files required for installation are
>   available and restart installation.

After looking around on the web, I try the following:

- One error, click the 'X' instead of close to restart the installation. Did this about 10 times, no luck.
- Reset CMOS, removed all RAM but 1 stick.
- Tried installing with mobo SATA drivers
- Bought a refurbished HD, same error at 50%. Tried all the above with the new drive.

I would hate to take it in to a local shop since they massively overcharge, is there anything else to try?

The original drive installs openSUSE 13.2 with no complaints, so it would seem that the drive is alright. I re-burned the Windows 7 ISO and tried all the above steps.

I can install Windows 7 on VirtualBox with no problems with that ISO.

Is it possible that it is the DVD drive even though I used it to install Linux, can’t burn DVD’s properly?

Comment: If you're having issues with the OS and also installation, I would be going towards HW issue. Though you have already tried many things. Still, there isn't any time when you're "due for a reinstall" unless the user breaks the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that ISO works straight into VirtualBox means the issue is on the burning process. I would try:

- To burn it slower.
- To burn it on another PC.
- To generate the MD5 checksum of the ISO with something like [WinMD5](http://winmd5.com/) or similar, then burn it and try to calculate its [checksum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/calculate-md5sum-of-a-cd-dvd).